# How to remove the last character from last string in a While loop?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, while-loop

I am trying to insert a PHP loop with data from my mysql database inside a Google Charts script.

My result from the database looks like this:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results(
    "Query");
```

The loop that I am trying to make is supposed to look like this

```
['$result',  $result],
```

And this is what I have come up with so far

```
$count = 0;
while ($count < count($result)) {
    echo "['" . $result[$count]->dato . "', " . $result[$count]->vaegt . "].<br>";
    $count++;
    }
```

Which create the string that I am looking for. The problem is that I need to remove the comma from the last string in the loop.

I have tried the function LTRIM, but it removes it from every string in the loop, not just the last.

What would be the best solution to fix this problem?

Comment: Use `json_encode`, it is already invented.

Comment: `.<br>` is also wrong (`<br>` is a HTML tag that doesn't belong in JSON and the `.` doesn't belong there either). Like previous comment says, use json_encode to turn an array into JSON. All you need to do is to make sure that you have a PHP array with the format/structure you want and encode that.

Comment: But the json_encode seems to output the wrong format? According to the Google line chart documentation I think the correct format should be ['data',  data],

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use count() for a fixed result in a loop. It may look convenient, but it's slower as it performs the operation over and over on each iteration. Assign the count result to a variable first. And personally, I would use a for() loop here.

Secondly, you need to use a condition inside the loop. Rather than trying to remove the last comma just run a check on the iteration count, if it's not last then add a comma.

```
$count = count($result);
for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)
{
    echo "....";
    if($i < $count)
    {
        echo ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
The for loop works great. But the IF statements doesn't seems to work.
It looks like it still echoes the comma for the last string in the loop?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a raw example of what you can do. I corrected the answer, should do exactly what you want now. It is generally preferable to use 0 as the starting point because it works better with arrays. I changed that to 1 to suit your occasion. Alternatively, you could subtract 1 from $count, i. e. $count = count($result)-1. And <= gives the loop just one more round to get all the output and the condition to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_encode, I think it will give you the kind of output you want.

Like this :

```
$arr = array();

foreach ( $result as $res ) {

    $dato = $res->dato;
    $vaegt = $res->vaegt;

    $arr[$dato] = $vaegt; 

}

$output = json_encode($arr);
```

Then pass $output to JS and use it like this :

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable("your JSON variable");

var options = {
 title:your option,
 legend:your option,
 chartArea:your option
};

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("the ID of the HTML element in which you want to output the result"));

chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: But the json_encode seems to output the wrong format? According to the Google line chart documentation I think the correct format should be ['data', data],

Comment: Please see my edited answer and tell me if you got it.